# How to extract apk file from PC?

Tags: android, xml, apk

I am able to extract my application apk file from PC. I am using the steps are

Add .zip after myapp.apk.zip

The APK file has been extracted successfully. But I am not able to see the XML file content.

The XML file has been incorrect format. This is my application. Learning Purpose Only.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12259460/decompling-an-android-apk/12259586#12259586

Comment: the best tutorial for this follow the link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/android-getting-source-code-from-an-apk-file

Comment: Detailed Steps:http://stackoverflow.com/a/6081365/543711

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Decompiling Android APPs using APKTool

Open command prompt and run below command.

```
apktool d apkfile ./FolderName
```

For More Information.[Video Tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tJrWeoGXpDY).